# Using JavaScript and PHP for the value of a href attribute

Tags: javascript, php

In my code bellow I would like to replace the string `#customer` with `window.location.hash`.

```
echo '<th><a href="?sort-by=email&order='. $this->order .'#customer">E-Mail</a></th>';
```

How would it be possible to mix JavaScript with PHP in my case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't really a matter of PHP.

Just remove the hash as it is right now in the PHP, then we can take it client-side and you can add it there.  For instance, you'd make your PHP like this instead:

```
echo '<th><a href="?sort-by=email&order='. $this->order .'">E-Mail</a></th>';
```

(Simply removing the hash)

Then in JavaScript, we'd do this:

```
Element.href = Element.href + window.location.hash;
```

Where `Element` is the DOM selector method for the `<a>` tag.

**EDIT** Or if you have jQuery handy:

```
$("a").each(function(){
  $(this).attr("href", 
    $(this).attr("href") + window.location.hash
  )
});
```

Comment: Thank you, how comes your jQuery code works when the selector is `a` but not if I want it to be a class name?

Comment: It doesn't? Are you sure you're doing the selector right? E.g. `"a.hashed"` or `".hashed"`?

Comment: @RezaSaadati, Strange.  It appears to work for me in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6huh99pj/).  (using `.html()` instead for visual reasons)

Comment: I noticed that this has nothing to do with your code. I even tried `$(".myClass").click(function() { alert('test'); });` and there's nothing happening when I click that item. Not even an error. I will need to figure out what's wrong but thanks anyway for your great answer!